# How do I stop the two jquery libraries from conflicting with each other?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

My page, that contains a couple of slides functioned perfectly with just js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js.

I recently introduced a top banner to my webpage (www.ug-mart.com) with googles CDN , but the top banner didnt work. I have had to remove js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js for the top  banner to work.

Having removed js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js everything that initially worked well now doesn't work. Only the top banner works. It seems like i cant have both   and js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js on the same page.

Is there a way to stop the the two jquery libraries from conflicting, and collaborate?

Looking forward to your reply.

SirBT

Comment: @safarov - it's not quite clear what you mean. I suspect you mean "Can we see what code you have so far?"

Comment: @SirBT - open out a JavaScript console in your browser, and reload your development site. You'll probably see an error relating to your issue. Also: why do you want to load jQuery twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can safely use jQuery along with other libraries using [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). usually, it's a conflict of the use of the `$` function name.

i prefer doing jquery in the "closure" method:

```
(function($){

    //i can use "$" safely in here

}(jQuery));
```

also, if you are using multiple versions of jQuery, then don't. just download the latest and use it. it should still cater some of the old API.

---

[heres a sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/qxVeE/2/) to show how this works:

```
//lets hijack the "$"
$ = (function() {
    return {
        libName: "some other library using $"
    }
}());

//create a closure for us to use "$"
(function($) {

    //we can now use the $ safely in this closure  
    $('body').text('hello world! in the body!');

    //let's check "$" in here
    console.log('in here, "$" is jQuery:',$);

}(jQuery));

//let's check "$" out here
console.log('out here, "$" is:', $);​
```

Comment: your solution sounds novel, can you please elaborate on your code. Like add an alert function inside the function for clarity?

Answer (score 2):

See jQuery's [$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Although, you'd really be better off, reestablishing whatever plugin requires older jQuery and make use of new version only.

Comment: I followed your advice and it worked out. Thank you. Prior to that I did try the:

Comment: I tried the:   <script>
         jQuery.noConflict();
     
       // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
         jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery("div").hide(); 
        }); which didnt work for me, however when I removed the old jquery library and and replaced it with the new one all the jquery plugins in my page started working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Does `$.noConflict()` works?
Import the js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js first and use `$.noConflict()` to register js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js.  Then use another code block and import another version of jQuery. In the end, rewrite the top banner using `jQuery.xxx()` instead of `$.xxx()`

I think this should be work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace any one of them as specified:-
 Declare in any one of them

```
$a = jQuery.noConflict();
```

**Replace all $ of that file by $a in that file**

Comment: I tried this and this work. I used it as documented in: [link] http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: I am sorry I meant to say that your solution didnt work. Besides it seems that jQuery.noConflict() only works when the JQuery library is alongside another JavaScript, and not alongside another JQuery library version...

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer.
add this at the end of your scripts.

```
<script src=""></script>
<script src=""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict(true);
</script>
```